# PHP: curl_init() giving NULL although created the resource

Tags: php, api, curl

I'm facing an error:

`Warning: curl_exec() expects parameter 1 to be resource, null given in`

`$json_string = curl_exec($variable_curl);`

I'm not sure what was wrong. I have

```
function __construct() {

      $variable_curl = curl_init(); //Create a new cURL resource

    }
```

I've confirmed the curl binding is working correctly because I used it without creating a library.

Based on that error, I can only tell $variable_curl wasn't created as a cURL resource correctly/non at all. But by looking at the `function __construct` above, I've done it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is `$variable_curl` a global variable?  If not, it won't be visible outside of your constructor.  If so, you need to declare it as such inside the function:

```
global $variable_curl;
```